# Libreoffice calc - how to write a same value into a range

Tags: range, libreoffice, basic

I know how to 'select' a range in LO (7.2.4.1) Calc BASIC ....

```
ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet.getCellRangeByName("D1:H6")
```

But how to write a value, e.g. "1", into that range using BASIC?

```
myRange = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet.getCellRangeByName("D1:H6")
myRange.Value = 1
```

Gives an "property or method not found" error. But I can't find any properties or values to go after Range to allow me to do what I want. Flailing around and trying

```
myRange.setValue = 1
myRange.writeValue = 1
myRange.setString = "1"
```

and numerous other variants don't work either.

Would really appreciate the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit the value of an individual cell, but not the entire range. You will have to iterate over all the cells in the range one at a time, changing the value of each of them.

```
Sub Set1ToD1H6
    myRange = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet.getCellRangeByName("D1:H6")
    For i = 0 To myRange.getRows().getCount()-1
        For j = 0 To myRange.getColumns().getCount()-1
            myRange.getCellByPosition(j, i).setValue(1)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

But since the read-write operation to a cell is comparable in time to the read-write operation to a whole range, it is preferable to use another method - to prepare data in an array and write from it to a range in one operation:

```
Sub Set1ToRange
    myRange = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet.getCellRangeByName("D1:H6")
    dataOfRange = myRange.getData()
    For i = LBound(dataOfRange) To UBound(dataOfRange)
        For j = LBound(dataOfRange(i)) To UBound(dataOfRange(i))
            dataOfRange(i)(j) = 1
        Next j
    Next i
    myRange.setData(dataOfRange)
End Sub
```

(For your example, this will be approximately 30 times faster, for a larger range the time winnings will be even more significant)

The [**.getData() and .setData()**](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/chart/XChartDataArray.html#getData) methods work on numeric range values. To work with text strings (and numbers), use [**.getDataArray()  and .setDataArray()**](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XCellRangeData.html#getDataArray), for working with cell formulas use [**.getFormulaArray() and .setFormulaArray()**](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XCellRangeFormula.html#getFormulaArray)

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the help.
I had thought that a solution using nested for/next loops would be able to do it
but it seemed like my "proposed code" would be so useful and common that there
was probably a method or property to do it in the way I was thinking.
But all my searches into it drew a blank suggesting it's never done in my way. 
Oh well... thanks once again and for replying so rapidly. :D

Comment: Probably, you mean "...in Excel and VBA"? Excel and Calc spreadsheet architecture is very different. This is similar to how in Excel you can get .Text for an individual cell, but not get it for a range. Just take it as inevitable, as a natural disaster - there is nothing you can do about it, so you adjust to the circumstances.

Comment: I do come from past Excel VBA experience. I did like VBA very much but I feel I have to move to Free and Open Source Software (FOSS) and to support it (e.g via monthly donations). What's more, after a few months of prep, I finally removed Windows on my Daily driver laptop and now run Linux Mint, and it's going great! Now I'm so happy to begin learning LO's Basic although I'm pretty scared of UNO/dispatcher!

Comment: Oh, @Miklos, I have been afraid of the dispatcher for almost 20 years - it is so verbose and indistinct! But there is a way out - do not use the dispatcher, write the code as [**Andrew Pitonyak**](https://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) recommends in [**his book**](https://www.pitonyak.org/AndrewMacro.odt) (you do not need to read it from beginning to end, use this as a reference book - find the appropriate section in the table of contents and take the code snippet that you need today and now). In addition, [**MRI**](https://youtu.be/DHgblImh4lQ) will provide significant assistance in creating macros