# libreoffice calc how to loop in a named range

Tags: libreoffice, named-ranges, calc, contiguous

I have a range of cells named, with not contiguous cells (NOT rectangular range)

I need to assign a background value and color to each cell in this range.

In the macro, naming works. Is it possible to assign a background value and color to all cells in the range in one statement?

Otherwise, if I have to make a loop, how to write it? (what I wrote does not work:

> Error PROPERTY OR METHOD NOT FOUND: GETROWS

Thank you for your help

```
sub addColorToNameGameBoard()

Dim myDocument As Object
Dim zoneOfNames As Object
Dim gameRangeName As String
Dim gameRangeNameCoordinates As String
Dim oCellAdress As New com.sun.star.table.CellAddress

myDocument = Thiscomponent

gameRangeNameCoordinates = "Feuille1.$B$5:$C$7~Feuille1.$D$4:$H$8" 

gameRangeName = "plateauDeJeu" 

zoneOfNames = myDocument.NamedRanges 
If zoneOfNames.hasByName(gameRangeName) then 
    zoneOfNames.removeByName(gameRangeName) 
end If
zoneOfNames.addNewByName(gameRangeName, gameRangeNameCoordinates ,oCellAdress,0)'


Dim myGameBoard as Object
myGameBoard = zoneOfNames.getByName(gameRangeName)
'KO myGameBoard.BackColor = rgb(255,0,0)
'myGameBoard.CellBackColor = RGB(100, 0 ,100)
Dim ReferredCells as Object
Dim aRangeAddress as Object

oReferredCells = myGameBoard.getReferredCells()
aRangeAddress = oReferredCells.getRangeAddress()

Dim oSheet As Object
oSheet = myDocument.getSheets().getByName("Feuille1") 'Sheet1
Dim oCellRange As Object    
oCellRange = oSheet.getCellRangeByName(gameRangeName) 

Dim myCell as Object
Dim i as long, j as long
For i = 0 To oCellRange.getRows().getCount()-1
    For j = 0 To oCellRange.getColumns().getCount()-1
        myCell = oCellRange.getCellByPosition(i,j)
        myCell.setValue(4)
        myCell.cellbackcolor = RGB(50,60,70) 
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

I tried different syntax to get number of rows and columns, nothing worked

Comment: Please translate the identifiers from your native language to English when posting code. -- What did you find in the documentation concerning getting rows and columns, and why did it not help you? -- Please [edit] your question to add new information, do not post comments. This is not a forum.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the color of an entire range in one line is not difficult: specify the name of some style with the design you want for the range's `.CellStyle` property, and the entire range will be instantly redrawn. The situation is a little worse with assigning a certain value to each cell. As explained in this answer - [**Libreoffice calc - how to write a same value into a range**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70330666/14094617), you will have to use row and column loops. And the situation is very bad with the ranges that you described using the tilde - there are no built-in tools for processing such constructions. This means that you will have to process each part of the address separately. In general, the solution code could look like this:

```
sub nommerAireDeJeu()

Dim monDocument As Object
Dim zoneDeNoms As Object
Dim nomDeLaPlageDeJeu As String
Dim coordonneesDeLaPlageDeJeu As String
Dim oCellAdress As New com.sun.star.table.CellAddress

monDocument = Thiscomponent

coordonneesDeLaPlageDeJeu = "Feuille1.$B$5:$C$7~Feuille1.$D$4:$H$8" 
nomDeLaPlageDeJeu = "plateauDeJeu" 

zoneDeNoms = monDocument.NamedRanges 
If zoneDeNoms.hasByName(nomDeLaPlageDeJeu) then 
    zoneDeNoms.removeByName(nomDeLaPlageDeJeu) 
end If
zoneDeNoms.addNewByName(nomDeLaPlageDeJeu, coordonneesDeLaPlageDeJeu ,oCellAdress,0)'

Dim oStyleFamilies As Variant
Dim nouveauStyle As Variant
    oStyles = monDocument.getStyleFamilies().getByName("CellStyles")
    If Not oStyles.hasByName(nomDeLaPlageDeJeu) Then
        nouveauStyle = monDocument.createInstance("com.sun.star.style.CellStyle")
        nouveauStyle.ParentStyle = oStyles.getByIndex(0).getName() ' "Default"
        oStyles.insertByName(nomDeLaPlageDeJeu, nouveauStyle)
        nouveauStyle.setPropertyValue("CellBackColor", RGB(50,60,70) )
    EndIf

Dim aAdresses As Variant 
Dim aRanges As Variant, aRange As Variant, aRngData As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, m As Long, n As Long
    aAdresses = Split(coordonneesDeLaPlageDeJeu, "~")
    For i = LBound(aAdresses) To UBound(aAdresses)
        aRanges = monDocument.getSheets().getCellRangesByName(aAdresses(i))
        For j = LBound(aRanges) To UBound(aRanges)
            aRange = aRanges(j)
            aRngData = aRange.getData()
            For m = LBound(aRngData) To UBound(aRngData)
                For n = LBound(aRngData(m)) To UBound(aRngData(m))
                    aRngData(m)(n) = 12345
                Next n
            Next m
            aRange.setData(aRngData)
            aRange.CellStyle = nomDeLaPlageDeJeu
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
doc = ThisComponent
sheet = doc.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
group = doc.createInstance("com.sun.star.sheet.SheetCellRanges")
Dim indexColumn as long, indexLine as long

range1 = sheet.getCellRangeByName("Feuille1.$B$5:$C$7")
range2 = sheet.getCellRangeByName("Feuille1.$D$4:$H$8")

group.addRangeAddress(range1.RangeAddress, False)
group.addRangeAddress(range2.RangeAddress, False)

MsgBox group.RangeAddressesAsString 
For Each individualRange In group
     For indexLine = 0 To individualRange.getRows().getCount()-1
        For indexColumn = 0 To individualRange.getColumns().getCount()-1
            myCell = individualRange.getCellByPosition(indexColumn,indexLine )
            myCell.setValue(4)
            myCell.cellbackcolor = RGB(50,60,70) 
        Next indexColumn
    Next indexLine 
Next individualRange
```

Comment: Some text with explanation is very useful

Answer (score 0):

The solution I was looking for:

```
option vbasupport 1

Sub Main

dim myRange as object

myRange=range("B5:C7,D4:H8")

myRange.value="X"

' Xray myRange plante (boucle)

myRange.CellRange.CellBackColor= RGB(50,60,70)

End Sub
```