# From one column generate a table with two columns

Tags: vba, libreoffice-calc

I need macro to look in sheet A to a specific column with values and generate in a already existing sheet B  in a specific location of sheet B a table with two columns  the first column with the values found in the column without repetitions and the second column  with the counting for the correspondent values

I tried this macro but get error message

> "BASIC runtime error. Property or method not found: setValue."

```
Sub GenerateUniqueValueTable()
    Dim oSheetA As Object
    Dim oSheetB As Object
    Dim oSourceRange As Object
    Dim oTargetRange As Object
    Dim oUniqueValues As Object
    Dim oCell As Object
    Dim i As Long

    ' Set the source sheet (Sheet A) and source range (adjust as needed)
    oSheetA = ThisComponent.getSheets().getByName("BD-direta")  
    oSourceRange = oSheetA.getCellRangeByName("P1:P2047")

    ' Set the target sheet (Sheet B) and target range (adjust location as needed)
    oSheetB = ThisComponent.Sheets.getByName("Estatistica") 
    oTargetRange = oSheetB.getCellRangeByName("B64:C64")  

    ' Create a new table header
    oTargetRange.setValue("Unique Value")
    oTargetRange.getCellByPosition(1, 0).setString("Count")

    ' Get unique values and their counts
    oUniqueValues = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.container.UniqueElementsContainer")
    For Each oCell In oSourceRange
        If Not oUniqueValues.has(oCell.String) Then
            oUniqueValues.insert(oCell.String, 1)
        Else
            oUniqueValues.replaceByIndex(oUniqueValues.indexOf(oCell.String), oUniqueValues.getByIndex(oUniqueValues.indexOf(oCell.String)) + 1)
        End If
    Next

    ' Populate the target sheet
    For i = 0 To oUniqueValues.getCount() - 1
        oSheetB.getCellByPosition(2, i + 1).setString(oUniqueValues.getByIndex(i))
        oSheetB.getCellByPosition(3, i + 1).setValue(oUniqueValues.getByIndex(i))
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is no `setValue()` method on the "cell range" object, [**this is only available for a single cell**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70330666/14094617).

But that's not the only reason this code won't work.
To write the string "Unique Value" to a cell, use the `setString()` method instead of `setValue()`, which is designed to write numeric values.

Executing a line

```
oUniqueValues = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.container.UniqueElementsContainer")
```

doomed to failure - there is no UniqueElementsContainer interface in the [**module com.sun.star.container**](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/namespacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1container.html). Therefore, you must write the code to count unique values yourself. It could be something similar to this:

```
Sub countUnique(key As Variant, aData As Variant)
Dim l&, r&, m&, N&, i&
    l = LBound(aData)
    r = UBound(aData) + 1
    N = r
    While (l < r) 
        m = l + Int((r - l) / 2)
        If aData(m)(0) < key Then l = m + 1 Else r = m
    Wend
    If r = N Then
        ReDim Preserve aData(0 To N)
        aData(N) = Array(key, 1)
    ElseIf aData(r)(0) = key Then
        aData(r)(1) = aData(r)(1) + 1
    Else
        ReDim Preserve aData(0 To N)
        For i = N - 1 To r Step -1
            aData(i + 1) = aData(i)
        Next i
        aData(r) = Array(key, 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

For not very large data sets (seven to ten thousand values) this will work quite quickly.

Now your macro that will perform the task could be like this:

```
Sub GenerateUniqueValueTable()
Dim oSheets As Object, oSheetA As Object, oSheetB As Object
Dim oSourceRange As Object, aData As Variant, aUniqueValues() As Variant
Dim oTargetRange As Object
Dim i As Long
    oSheets = ThisComponent.getSheets()
    ' Set the source sheet (Sheet A) and source range (adjust as needed)
    oSheetA = oSheets.getByName("BD-direta")  
    oSourceRange = oSheetA.getCellRangeByName("P1:P2047")

    ' Set the target sheet (Sheet B) and target range (adjust location as needed)
    oSheetB = oSheets.getByName("Estatistica") 

    ' Create a new table header
    oSheetB.getCellRangeByName("B64").setString("Unique Value")
    oSheetB.getCellRangeByName("C64").setString("Count")

    ' Get unique values and their counts
    aData = oSourceRange.getDataArray()
    For i = LBound(aData) To UBound(aData)
        Call countUnique(aData(i)(0), aUniqueValues)
    Next

    ' Populate the target sheet
    oTargetRange = oSheetB.getCellRangeByPosition(1, 64, 2, 64+UBound(aUniqueValues))
    oTargetRange.setDataArray(aUniqueValues)
End Sub
```

*I understand that your question related specifically to writing a macro. However, I have to say that if you were to add some kind of data header (like Keys) to the data in the 'BD-direta'.P1 cell, you would get the same result in just a few clicks using [**Pivot Table**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/12090100.html?DbPAR=CALC&HID=.uno:DataDataPilotRun#bm_id3153822)*
[image: PivotTable instead macro]